# Calculating e using loops

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate e iteratively, but my code gives me 2. Any idea what could be wrong? Because I'm completely stuck.

```
public class iteratee {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long limit = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

            limit = limit + 1/factorial(i);

        }

        System.out.println(limit);

    }

    static int factorial(int n) {

        int factorial = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            factorial = factorial * j;
        }

        return factorial; 

    }

}
```

Comment: `limit` (I assume "e") is an integer type.  Can't have decimal points in an int.  Switch to `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long` is a type that represents an integer value; it's not going to reflect any decimals at all.  Change `limit` to have type `double` and write `limit = limit + 1.0 / factorial(i)`, which will avoid integer division being used.

Comment: Also, integer division is not going to result in a good answer.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know 1 / factorial(i) gives a rounded integer. (0)

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
    long limit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        limit = limit + 1/factorial(i);

    }
```

into

```
    double limit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        limit = limit + 1.0 / factorial(i);
    }
```

to have a `double` for `limit` and `1.0` instead of `1`.